# How can I edit a movie with Movie Studio?

Tags: video

Using Movie Studio, how can I edit a video, specifically split it to remove a portion of the video? I've figured out how to apply effects and transitions, but I want to clip a portion. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search brought up this article at http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-edit-video-with-movie-studio-on-your-android-tablet.

While I don't have a tablet, I have played with Movie Studio before, and it looks like all you have to do is tap the timeline at the bottom of your clip, and drag the arrows that appear on its edges to trim it. This only trims the edges off, so if you want to take a part out of the middle, I would re-add the clip (so you have two copies of it in your timeline), and then drag the arrows on the ends of the copy so you only have the part you want, without getting rid of the beginning of the clip from the original.